# Any modern edition of the works of Archimedes containing the original Greek?

Tags: geometry, math-history

As best as I can tell the only authoritative collection of the works of Archimedes containing the original Greek is that of Johann Heiberg, "Archimedis Opera Omnia cum Commentariis Eutocii" (1880). There is, of course, the Loeb Classical Library volume (1962), but that only has a selection of Archimedes, not all of his works.

Is there any edition more modern than Heiberg's that has the original text of all Archimedes works?

Comment: Check out the [Perseus Project](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu). Their primary mission was/is to compile everything about classical Graeco-Roman culture.

Comment: [Reviel Netz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reviel_Netz) has started a [new edition](https://books.google.it/books?id=msyO12v3tqcC&pg=PR3).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA From what I can tell, Netz's book is just a translation. It does not have the original Greek text.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I know that. If you read my question, you will see I already have access to Heiberg's Greek text. I want to know if a more modern edition of the Greek text has been published since 1880. There is not just one Greek text. There are hundreds of different manuscripts of Archimedes, so making a Greek text is not a trivial task and I want to know if anybody has published a Greek text since 1880.